# NodeJS with AngularJS, required HTML file isn't databinding global variable across controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, data-binding

I'm importing a simple HTML file inside my NodeJS file. The HTML file contains a databinded variable which I set inside my controller. The problem is, when the NodeJS file imports the HTML file,  {{name}} doesn't get databinded and what gets shown is just "{{name}}". However, if I view file.html directly, then the actual value is shown, so I'm not sure if it's a server side issue. Here's my code:

mycontrollers.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.value('name', {content: "BOBBY "});


app.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', 'name', function($scope, name) {

    $scope.name = name.content;
}]);
```

app.js:

```
    var file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public/file.html').toString();
```

file.html

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body ng-controller="mycontroller">
    {{name}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mycontrollers.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that it is a relative path issue? In other words, when you html file is loaded, is it actually requesting the JS file from the URL where you think it is? It's hard to tell what URL the browser is requesting your html file from just by looking at your example. Check the network tab in Chrome Dev tools to see if the request for the JS is being returned.

Comment: there's no error when reading the file, so I'm assuming the path is correct, not sure if it is an issue with how global variables work or how the server handles html files that have databinded variables

Comment: can you post the rest of the app.js code that actually handles the request and sends the response?

Comment: I got it working now. I created a json variable within my node.js app that could be databinded to the html. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anyplace in your code where "app" is defined. Have you bootstrapped you application correctly and created a module:

```
 var app = angular.module('myapp', []); //this string should match the value in ng-app from your HTML file
```

Check out the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) for an example:

```
    var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

    phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.phones = [
            {'name': 'Nexus S',
                'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
            {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
                'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
            {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
                'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
        ];
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I had that already in there. That wasn't the issue. As I mentioned, when I view file.html directly in my browser, the {{name}} gets databinded correctly, but when I'm importing the file from my app.js, that {{name}} doesn't get databinded